# PHP equivalent of JavaEE commandLinks

Tags: php, jakarta-ee, web

I have some code copied from some book about JavaEE.

```
<h:form>         
        <h:dataTable value="#{lekarzBean.lista}" var="lekarz">            
            <h:column>      
                <f:facet name="header">Edytuj</f:facet>       
                <h:commandLink value="Edytuj" action="#{lekarzBean.zaladujDoEdycji}" actionListener="#{lekarzBean.lekarzListener}">            
                    <f:param name="lekarzID" value="#{lekarz.id}" />       
                </h:commandLink>           
            </h:column>             
            <h:column>             
                <f:facet name="header">Usun</f:facet>   
                <h:commandLink value="Usun" action="#{lekarzBean.usun}" actionListener="#{lekarzBean.lekarzListener}">    
                    <f:param name="lekarzID" value="#{lekarz.id}" />     
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:column>         
            <h:column>             
                <f:facet name="header">Imie</f:facet>             
                <h:outputText value="#{lekarz.imie}" />      
            </h:column>             
            <h:column>              
                <f:facet name="header">Nazwisko</f:facet>   
                <h:outputText value="#{lekarz.nazwisko}" />     
            </h:column>              
            <h:column>                
                <f:facet name="header">Specjalizacja</f:facet>             
                <h:outputText value="#{lekarz.specjalizacja}" />     
            </h:column>         
            <h:column>             
                <f:facet name="header">Przychodnia</f:facet>          
                <h:outputText value="#{lekarz.przychodnia==null? 'Brak':lekarz.przychodnia.nazwa}"/>          
            </h:column>        
        </h:dataTable>      
    </h:form>
```

And as result I have this:

[Picture](http://screenshooter.blob.core.windows.net/engine4files/jecfrzivgvvvlcxybukygpkkhhnjtgelfrcxwqeriptnwuxoyjmfqrxttsxkmzbzqjquaaclpspqvwonjykjuyvntiedtufiouxmedoyhbpxchxwekboprerocarvyrv)

I want to do the same in PHP, but I don't know how I can make equivalent of that two commandLinks. I know, that I can do it using $_GET array, but I don't want to show parameters in my URL.
How can I achieve the same effect in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood commandLink is calling a javascript function that uses POST to send parameters to the server.

To achieve the same thing in plein PHP you can do an HTTP POST by calling a javascript function on your onclick attribute